# Pyparsing SetParseAction trouble

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am a new-bee to pyparsing I am trying to experiment with setParseAction but it is not being called sometimes.
Here is the code

```
def fun():
    comdty_tok = StringStart() + Word(alphas) + StringEnd()
    comdty_tok.setParseAction(call_back)
    comdty_tok.leaveWhitespace()
    return comdty_tok

def call_back(p):
    print 'Calling ....'
    print p

class ComdtyTok(Token):

     comdty_tok = StringStart() + Word(alphas) + StringEnd()
     comdty_tok.setParseAction(call_back)
     comdty_tok.leaveWhitespace()
     parseImpl = comdty_tok.parseImpl

class SymParser(object):
    tok =  ComdtyTok()
    @staticmethod
    def parse(symbol):
       p = SymParser.tok.parseString(symbol)
       print p
       print "Second"
       x = fun()
       x.parseString(symbol)
       return p

SymParser.parse('ABCD')
```

I dont understand why the setParseAction is not called for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I just played with pyparsing for the first time, so ...

In initializing the class variable `comdty_tok` you never actually call `parseString()`, therefore the callback associated with the parse object is never called.

Comment: I don't think this is it - first statement in parse is `p = SymParser.tok.parseString(symbol)`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: You're right. I've just spent about 1/2 an hour in the guts of this puppy and frankly, I'm confused. Setting `setDebug()` on the two token instances only adds to the mystery. The first invocation shows no debugging output at all, while the second acts as expected. If you initialize `SymParser.tok` with ` = fun()` instead, all is sweetness and light.

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is that I did not really intend for classes like Token to be extended in the manner that you have done. I suspect that in your delegation to the contained `cmdty_tok` attribute that you have omitted exposing some other attribute, such as `parseAction`, which would normally be referenced at parse time by `parseImpl`. On the other hand, your implementation of `fun()` is very consistent with other helpers and closures I have used and seen used, and not surprisingly, this approach works.

What are you trying to accomplish with `ComdtyTok`?

Comment: Basically I want to abstract all the regular expressions within one class, I read this we can do that by inheriting the Token class, but I am not sure how the control is flowing with this .